# ejabberd error with with utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 16.01 that works well with MySQL, the problem is that it store only the regular emoji not the 4-bytes emoji. If I use a terminal, connect to the database, set the charset to utf8mb4 and run insert query, I can insert all type of icons, so the db is configured in the right way!

So i ejabberd put a message in offline storage all icons of 4-Bytes become "?????????" is there a way to set the charset to utf8mb4 for ejabberd mod offline?

How can I fix it? Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no ejabberd 1.6 ...

Comment: Sorry, /opt/ejabberd-16.01/

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. Ensure you have ejabberd 16.02 or newer that forces UTF8MB4 as default for emoji retrieval (Insertion is already in UTF8MB4 since years, if the table is correctly defined)
2. Ensure your MySQL schema has been properly created with UTFMB4 support.

Comment: ok, with the versione 16.03 all works fine!!! thanks! i'm recompiling a module but with this new version i obtain this error: mod_http_offline.erl: undefined parse transform 'lager_transform' any ideas? i use this to compile :erlc -DNO_EXT_LIB -I /opt/ejabberd-16.03/lib/ejabberd-16.03/include/ mod_http_offline.erl

Comment: Do not compile with the no_ext_lib flag.